# Opening File after upload in Typescript (Angular 5)

Tags: angular, typescript

How to open a file by 'on click' event after uploading in `angular 5` (typescript) ?

Comment: your question is not precise enough. what kind of file is it ? do you want to open it in browser ?

Comment: All type of files, like .png, .pdf, .docx, etc any file I need to open it on click after uploading before sending to database i.e. before making a REST call

Comment: I want to open in dialog box not in browser

Comment: *in dialog box not in browser* this is a nonsense, if you want a Dialog, then it **is in your browser**. I presume what you want to do is to make your users download the file (and then the browser launches the appropriate program to open the file)